# Jooq notation for unnest with multiple arrays

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq, unnest

I want to mix in external *timezone per location* info to filter rows that has **timestamp without timezone** values.

How can I express in Jooq this SQL (Postgresql) snippet

```
WITH 
    now(locaton, value) AS (
        SELECT 
            * 
        FROM unnest(
            ARRAY[1,2]::BIGINT[],
            ARRAY['2017-05-28 09:30','2017-05-28 10:30']::TIMESTAMP[])
    ) 
SELECT * 
FROM now;
```

Less desirable but still working snippet is:

```
WITH 
    now(locaton, value) AS (
        SELECT 
            unnest(ARRAY[1,2]::BIGINT[]) as location,
            unnest(ARRAY['2017-05-28 09:30','2017-05-28 10:30']::TIMESTAMP[]) as value
    ) 
SELECT * 
FROM now;
```

Probably more correct one (blocked by [Add support for the SQL Standard WITH ORDINALITY clause #5799](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5799))

```
SELECT location, value
FROM 
  unnest(ARRAY[1,2]::BIGINT[]) WITH ORDINALITY as location
  JOIN unnest(ARRAY['2017-05-28 09:30','2017-05-28 10:30']::TIMESTAMP[]) WITH ORDINALITY as value 
  USING (ordinality);
```

To get

```
location    |        value
------------+---------------------
         1  | 2017-05-28 09:30:00
         2  | 2017-05-28 10:30:00
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Oh, really nice solution using `WITH ORDINALITY`. Perhaps that issue should get a higher priority.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I solved it using plain SQL

```
DSL
    .with("now", "location", "value")
    .as(
        create
            .select(
                DSL.field("location"),
                DSL.field("value")
            )
            .from(
                DSL
                    .table(
                        "UNNEST(?::BIGINT[]) WITH ORDINALITY",
                        DSL.val(Arrays.asList(1L, 2L).toArray())
                    )
                    .as("location")
                    .join(
                        DSL
                            .table(
                                "UNNEST(?::TIMESTAMP[]) WITH ORDINALITY",
                                DSL.val(
                                    Arrays.asList(
                                        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 05, 28, 9, 30),
                                        LocalDateTime.of(2017, 05, 28, 10, 30)
                                    ).toArray()
                                )
                            )
                            .as("value")
                    )
                    .using(
                        DSL.field("ordinality")
                    )
            )
    )
    .select()
    .from(DSL.table("now"));
```

Comment: You could still use `DSL.unnest()` and then wrap the result in plain SQL as such: `DSL.table("{0} WITH ORDINALITY", DSL.unnest(...))`

Comment: Suggested improvement substitutes `array_table` string instead of array parameter.