# jOOQ How do you unnest multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, jooq, postgresql-13

cf. `unnest ( anyarray, anyarray [, ... ] )` in [the psql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html#ARRAY-FUNCTIONS-TABLE)

The example given there:

```
select * from unnest(ARRAY[1,2], ARRAY['foo','bar','baz']) as x(a,b) →

 a |  b
---+-----
 1 | foo
 2 | bar
   | baz
```

I'd now like to use this feature to do a batch update.

I.e. something like

```
WITH
   updates as (
       SELECT * FROM unnest(
           target_ids,
           updated_foos
) as x(target_id, new_foo)
   )
UPDATE target t
    SET foo = u.new_foo
    FROM updates u
    WHERE t.id = u.target_id
;
```

where

- `target_ids` holds the ids of the entities to be updated
- `updated_foos` holds the updated property values
- property `foo` of entity with id `target_ids[i]` should be set to `updated_foos[i]`

The psql is quite straightforward: https://dbfiddle.uk/NRQ_ISM-

But there doesn't seem to be a corresponding jOOQ `unnest` overload that would let me do this. :(

I did find this 6y-old thread [Jooq notation for unnest with multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44235892/jooq-notation-for-unnest-with-multiple-arrays) and I suppose I could do it that way, too:

```kotlin
val targetId = "target_id"
val newFoo = "new_foo"

val updates = DSL // a table (targetId, newFoo) containing all updates to be done
    .name("updates")
    .fields(targetId, newFoo)
    .`as`(
        DSL.select(
            DSL.field(targetId),
            DSL.field(newFoo)
        ).from(
            DSL.table(
                "(SELECT * FROM unnest(?,?)) as x($targetId, $newFoo)",
                DSL.value(updatingTargets.toTypedArray()),
                DSL.value(newFoos.toTypedArray()),
            )
        )
    )

ctx
    .with(updates)
    .update(TARGET)
    .set(TARGET.FOO, updates.field(newFoo, String::class.javaObjectType))
    .from(updates)
    .where(TARGET.ID.eq(updates.field(targetId, Int::class.javaObjectType)))
    .execute()
```

(where `ctx: DSLContext`)

But I was hoping for a slightly less verbose solution that relies less on plain sql strings.

Answer (score 1):

This particular usage of "Enhanced `UNNEST`" (optional SQL feature S301 in the standard) is quite esoteric, but occasionally interesting. It could be supported in a future version of jOOQ (not yet in jOOQ 3.19):

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/15597

But you hardly ever really need it, given that you can just use the also standard SQL [`VALUES` constructor](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/table-expressions/values/), assuming your arrays always originate in client code.

```kotlin
values(row(1, "A"), row(2, "B"))
```

As you can see in this updated [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ZXQwiiOh), the example is equivalent to yours:

```sql
WITH
   updates as (
       SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        (2, 'hello'),
        (4, 'world')
       ) as x(target_id, new_foo)
   )
UPDATE target t
    SET foo = u.new_foo
    FROM updates u
    WHERE t.id = u.target_id
;
SELECT * FROM target;
```

Note, jOOQ has a [`org.jooq.Rows`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Rows.html) utility that allows for collecting a `Stream` to a `List<Row2<T1, T2>>` or `Array<Row2<T1, T2>>`, for example, though in Kotlin, you probably don't need that utility.